# Angular HttpClient constructor and abstract HttpHandler class

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I try understand why HttpClient constructor not have true implementation.

Actually the constructor include parameter typed as abstract class (HttpHandler). So why HttpHandler not have implementation? Or why his implementetion so secret to buried it deep in DI system?

And where I can find his implementation code?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I've found something on angular repo. [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e18a52e24a834f8795f8ed07b446f2a21ef28708/packages/common/http/src/backend.ts#L39) you can see that **HttpBackend** implements **HttpHandler**, but it's abstract too. But further you can find different implementations of **HttpBackend** like [HttpXhrBackend](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e18a52e24a834f8795f8ed07b446f2a21ef28708/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L68) or [JsonpClientBackend](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e18a52e24a834f8795f8ed07b446f2a21ef28708/packages/common/http/src/jsonp.ts#L48). **HttpXhrBackend** it's implementation that uses XMLHttpRequest API to send requests to a backend server. **JsonpClientBackend** - performs JSONP style requests (without using XMLHttpRequest object at all).

---

Overall **HttpHandler**
it's an abstraction of service that handles **HttpRequest** and returns **HttpResponse** in **Observable** manner, so it creates this Observable inside from **HttpEvents** that browser API provides. For example **XMLHttpRequest** has events like **onLoad**, **onError**, **onUpProgress** and **HttpXhrBackend** which is implementation of **HttpHandler** transforms all these events to **Observable stream**. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I still not understand why not follow after OOP principle, And put all into the constructor. Something like call to XMLHttpRequest  wrapper. Also I yet not sure understand what happened under hood when I Inject the HttlClient first time on my component constructor. I gues have some code register to DI system, that say: "If injectable is HtpClient please run the follow code"